# Workflow: when adding minutes to a date... what's the default time?

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, date-time

I have a workflow for sending notifications 63 minutes after a given date. I'm reading the date field and adding 63 minutes.

The date field doesn't have a time (it's configured as "date only"), so I was assuming that the default would be 0:00. But after running the workflow it seems that the default time is 10:00am, does that make sense? Why 10am?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this Microsoft article, in the Date and Time column, the time portion of the value is always 12:00 AM. I test in my environment, the default time is 12:00 AM. 
This may be caused by the your local time. You could directly set specific data in the workflow to avoid it. Or set default value in the Date and Time column.

Reference:
[Behavior and format of the date and time field](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/portals/configure/behavior-format-date-time-field)